# ASP.NET dynamically generate HTML with server controls

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

When i need to set some value to a Javacript, or any other part of the code, i usually use this:

```
 <script>
    <%# SomeFunction() %> 
 </script>
```

And this also works for HTML in the document body, like...

```
 <somehtmltag property="<%# SomeFunction2() %>">
```

And in the code behind i create the function that returns a string, with all the necessary code.

If i add some parameter to a user control like:

```
<ts:PeopleCard ID="us" runat="server" Visible="<%# IsVisivle() %>" />
```

It also works, but i try to create the entire user control it does not work.

```
<%# AddUserControl() %>

Function AddUserControl() as String
    Return "<ts:PeopleCard ID=""us"" runat=""server"" Visible=""true"" />"
End Function
```

I understand that this does not work, because this code must be processed by the server to be converted in the actual code.

The final HTML, it shows:

```
  <ts:PeopleCard ID="us" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

when it shouldn't, it should show the processed HTML\css by the server.

So my question is, is it possible to create a control this way? Is it possible to force ASP.NET to "re-process" the page, after I changed its contents in code behind?

I understand there's several other ways to do it. Including, creating the user control in conde behind.

But i need to know, if is possible to do this way...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have a parent tag that is runat server and you can then add your own object to it.

```
Dim newTag as New PeopleCard
newTag.Visible = true
pnl.Controls.Add(newTag)
```

An other option I've done is the past is to add a [RenderMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.rendermethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to a control. Each control have a [SetRenderMethodDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.setrendermethoddelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) function and it allows you to write directly to the HtmlTextWriter. This won't create an object for the controls you create yourself.